# facebook c# sdk and windows 8 Release preview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, build, facebook-c#-sdk

I downloaded the latest bits for facebook c# sdk  and there are build errors so I guess I am too early. Any idea when there might be a stable build. Thanks

Comment: I was able to compile the current release on Windows 8 without a problem.

Comment: yes but was it windows 8 release preview that was released about 3 weeks ago .. thanks

Comment: I don't know about the build, but I have run the 6.0.18 release bits on Windows 8 and they are working fine for me in http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

looks like my mistake was failing to use Nuget and I also had an old example but I am able to get a login using the example at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx